# Regular and irregular points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the following 2 examples, I am trying to find all the singular points of the given equations and determine whether each one is regular or irregular

I can determine the singular points of the equations but I am having some trouble determining if they are regular or irregular.

1)  $$x^2 (1-x^2)y'' + \frac {2}{x}y'+4y =0$$

The singular points of the equation are $x=\pm 1, 0$

The answer is that $0$ is irregular and $\pm 1$ regular but I am not sure why

2) $$xy'' + (1-x)y' +xy =0$$

The singular point is $0$ but why is this considered regular?

Do I have to consider the $p (x)$ term in each equation?

Comment: The coefficient of y" should be just x

Answer (score 3):

The definition of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point) :

For the ordinary differential equation: $$f''(x)+p_{1}(x)f'(x)+p_{0}(x)f(x)=0.\,$$

- Point $a$ is an ordinary point when functions $p_1(x)$ and $p_0(x)$ are analytic at $x = a$.
- Point $a$ is a regular singular point if $p_1(x)$ has a pole up to order $1$ at $x = a$ and $p_0$ has a pole of order up to $2$ at $x = a$.
- Otherwise, point a is an irregular singular point.

For your example 1)
$$x^2 (1-x^2)y'' + \frac {2}{x}y'+4y =0$$

we divide by the coefficient function of $y''$ to obtain:

$$y'' + \frac {2}{x^3 (1-x^2)}y'+\dfrac{4}{x^2 (1-x^2)}y =0.$$

The singular points are $x=0$ and $x=\pm 1$.  From the definition, we see that $x=0$ is an irregular singular point because it is a third order pole. $x=\pm 1$ are order $1$ poles of the coefficient function of $y'$ and also order $1$ poles of the coefficient function of $y$. Hence, we know that these are regular singular points.

**Can you do the next example?**

Comment: What is meant by pole?

Comment: pole = sigular point

Comment: I am getting a little confused,  when I plug I'm $\pm 1$  after we divided by the coefficient doesn't the second and third term go to 0? So how is it order 1 poles of the coedeficient y' and y

Comment: Note that $x^3(1-x^2)=x^3(1-x)^1(1+x)^1$ and $x^2(1-x^2)=x^2(1-x)^1(1+x)^1$. The powers are indicating the order of the pole/singular point.

Comment: So why is the pole order of p when x=0 3?

Comment: And why is the pole order 1 for both p and q and 1,-1

Comment: @jh123, What is the [multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial) of the root $x=0$ in the polynomial $f(x)=x^3(1-x^2)$ ? Same for the roots $x=\pm 1$ ?

Comment: So $f (x) = x^3 (1-x^2) = x^3 (1+x)(1-x)$ so now do I plug in x=0 to get $0^3 (1-0)$ ?

Comment: So then the order would be 3?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the first of your equations:

> $$x^2 (1-x^2)y'' + \frac {2}{x}y'+4y =0$$

Reducing it to standard form, the coefficients of  $y',y$ are $p(x)=\dfrac{2}{x^3(1-x^2)},q(x)=\dfrac 4{x^2(1-x^3)}$ respectively.

The functions $p,q$ each have poles on $x=0,\pm 1$, so they are singularities, or singular points.

> **Definition:** Now, we call a singular point $a$ to be **regular** if either $p$ or $q$ diverges as $x\to a$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to a}(x-a)p(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}(x-a)^2q(x)$ remain finite. Otherwise, we call it **irregular**.

This definition is equivalent to saying that $p$ has a pole of order at most $1$ at $x=a$ and $q$ has a pole of order at most $2$ at $x=a$ for $a$ to be **regular**, otherwise it's **irregular**

Now, notice that at $x=\pm 1$, $p$ has a pole of order $1\leq 1$ and $q$ has a pole of order $1\leq 2$, so $x=\pm 1$ is regular.

But at $x=0$, $p$ has a pole of order $3\gt 1$, so $x=0$ is irregular.

---

Can you follow the above and get the answer for your next example?

Here's a head start for you:

The coefficients of $y',y$ after reduction to standard form are:

> $$p(x)=\frac{1-x}x^2\quad\textrm{and}\quad q(x)=\frac 1x$$

Clearly, the only pole is at $x=0$ for both $p,q$. What is the order of the pole in $p,q$ ? Compute and compare with the definition.

Comment: What us meant by pole?

Comment: @jh123, A _pole_ is just another name for "singular point".

Comment: I'm a little confused when you say p has a pole order of 1 and q has a pole order of 1? What is meant by the order?

Comment: @jh123, Basically, a singular point (pole) $x=a$ of $f(x)$ is of order $n$ if it is the least positive integer such that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}x^nf(x)$ is finite.

Comment: This is equivalent to the multiplicity of the singular point (akin to the multiplicity of a root in a polynomial).

Comment: Still a little confused why when x =0 it has a pole of order 3, do I need to plug in x=0?

Comment: Does the x^3 term not come into consideration for multiplicity?

Comment: Typo in previous comment: The limit should be $\lim\limits_{x\to a}(x-a)^n f(x)$

Comment: @jh123, you needn't plug in anything. First of all, do you know the definition of _multiplicity_ of a root of a polynomial?

Comment: Side comment: The word pole evokes the image of the divergent "spike" appearing in the graph at the singularity. The spike is an obstruction to the analyticity of the function, so it is as if a "pole" is in the way.